# Optimising a join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, optimization

I am very inexperienced when it comes to optimising queries so any help would be much appreciated.

I currently have a 3 way join which takes + 10mins to execute. I am currently trying to test this so to have to wait that long is not ideal. Is there any way i can make it faster?

Current query:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT
S.[No],
S.[Date],
S.[No],
L.[No],
C.[Name],
C.[E-Mail],
C.[Order]
FROM [Customer] C
JOIN [Line] L
ON C.[No] = L.[No] 
JOIN [Sale] S 
ON S.[No] = L.[No] 
WHERE S.[Date] >= '2017-04-01'
AND L.[Type] = '2'
AND C.[Type] = '2'
```

As far as im aware none of the columns have indexes. Which would be the best columns to add indexes to?

Tables rows:

Customer: 80,000 rows

Line: 550,000 rows

Sale: 1,300,000 rows

I have initially altered this to join the smaller tables first but it doesn't seem to have made much difference.

thanks

Comment: `As far as im aware none of the columns have indexes.` Why?

Comment: @Siyual that is just the way its been set up by someone else

Comment: Well fix that then. The lack of indexes is very problematic. Do you have primary keys on these tables?

Comment: Well, the obvious solution would be to look at the query plan, and add indexes to the tables. Particularly on the `Sale`.`Date` column.

Comment: I suspect your query is logically flawed. And this is why you should post DDL for the tables involved. I don't know what "Line" represents, but is sounds appropriate that a customer is associated with a Sale. Joining both customer and sale on Line.No seems highly suspicious.

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/   execution plan might bring out more info for you.  My guess...C.[No], L.[NO], and s.[NO] are stored as characters not numbers, but I could be off...performance issues like this often come from char keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.[No], S.[Date], S.[No], L.[No],
       C.[Name], C.[E-Mail], C.[Order]
FROM [Customer] C JOIN
     [Line] L
     ON C.[No] = L.[No] JOIN
     [Sale] S 
     ON S.[No] = L.[No] 
WHERE S.[Date] >= '2017-04-01' AND L.[Type] = '1' AND C.[Type] = '1';
```

Here are suggestions:

1. Remove `SELECT DISTINCT` unless you really need it.  That adds unnecessary overhead.
2. Change `'1'` to just `1` if `Type` is numeric.  I would guess it it.
3. Add indexes on all the join keys.
4. Check the joins . . . I would be surprised if the same column is used for all tables.
5. You might want indexes on the columns in the `WHERE` clause.  However, I suspect the join keys are the real performance issue.

Under normal circumstances, such a query on three tables of that size should not be taking 10 minutes, which is why I suspect bad join keys.

Comment: is there any issues that adding indexes could cause? in terms of the rest of the database?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon . . . Indexes take up a bit more space on disk and can occupy memory.  They also slow down inserts, updates, and deletes a bit (usually a tiny bit).